# Calling C# code within Python3.6

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net, pythonnet

with absolutely no knowledge of coding in C#, I wish to call a C# function within my python code. I know there's quite a lot of Q&As around the same problem, but for some strange reason, i'm unable to import a simple c# class library from a sample python module.

Here's below as to what i've done -

> C# Class Library setup

I'm using the VS 2017 CE.

I create a new project `TestClassLibrary` under the type of `ClassLibrary(.NET Standard)`

The classes inside the project are as follows -

**MyClass.cs**

```
using System;
namespace TestClassLibrary
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string function()
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

This was built successfully, generating the `.dll` file under the `\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0` dir as `TestClassLibrary.dll`

Now, I switch over to python3.6 (running on a virtualenv, backed with pythonnet 2.3.0)

**main.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"<Ablsloute Path to \bin>\Debug\netstandard2.0")
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"TestClassLibrary")
from TestClassLibrary import MyClass
```

When i Run `python main.py`, the code fails with the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from TestClassLibrary import MyClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TestClassLibrary'
```

Should the code be -

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\TestClassLibrary\TestClassLibrary\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0")
import clr
clr.AddReference("TestClassLibrary.dll")
from TestClassLibrary import MyClass
```

I get -

```
clr.AddReference("TestClassLibrary.dll")
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'TestClassLibrary.dll'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

But when i ran the code below, the code runs as expected -

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import MessageBox
MessageBox.Show("Hello World!")
```

I've no idea of what i might be missing :(

Comment: you are using .NET Core assemblies, but pythonnet currently only partially supports .NET Core. Compile your C# code to .NET Framework 4.0+ instead.

Comment: Spot on @denfromufa :) 
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This is really janky but how I like to do things that are personal projects.
Python lets you send stuff to the command line really easily. C# can be run from command line. You probably see where I'm going with this.

Try adding C sharp to PATH. import os to python. then use this line of code when you want to run the C# script:

```
os.system("csc nameofscript.cs")
```

perhaps I've misunderstood, but this is how I would make it work on my machine